Why is my code giving as result Run time error 5?
I wrote the following code to copy and paste pictures from a folder to an existing presentation. However , every time I run it I receive the Error Run Time 5 which I am not able to solve. I tried to identify with problem with different msgbox controls but I cannot identify the right problem.
Sub CopiaFotoInPowerPointEsistenteSemplificato()
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPresentation As Object
    Dim pptSlide As Object
    Dim slideIndex As Integer
    Dim imgFolderPath As String
    Dim imgName As String
    Dim imgPath As String
    Dim imgCounter As Integer
    Dim imgPosArray(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As Single
    Dim imgWidth As Single
    Dim imgHeight As Single
    Dim pptFilePath As String

    ' Specifica il percorso della cartella contenente le immagini
    imgFolderPath = "C:\Users\Tuonomeutente\Desktop\Immagini\" ' Modifica questo percorso

    ' Verifica se la cartella esiste
    If Dir(imgFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "La cartella specificata non esiste!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Specifica il percorso della presentazione PowerPoint esistente
    pptFilePath = "C:\Users\Tuonomeutente\Desktop\Presentazione.pptx" ' Modifica questo percorso

    ' Verifica se il file di PowerPoint esiste
    If Dir(pptFilePath) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Il file della presentazione PowerPoint non esiste!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Inizializzazione di PowerPoint
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    If pptApp Is Nothing Then
        Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    pptApp.Visible = True
    
    ' Apri la presentazione esistente
    Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptFilePath)

    ' Verifica se la presentazione è stata aperta correttamente
    If pptPresentation Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Impossibile aprire la presentazione PowerPoint!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Definisci le posizioni delle immagini (4 per slide)
    imgPosArray(1, 1) = 50    ' Left della prima immagine
    imgPosArray(1, 2) = 50    ' Top della prima immagine
    imgPosArray(2, 1) = 400   ' Left della seconda immagine
    imgPosArray(2, 2) = 50    ' Top della seconda immagine
    imgPosArray(3, 1) = 50    ' Left della terza immagine
    imgPosArray(3, 2) = 300   ' Top della terza immagine
    imgPosArray(4, 1) = 400   ' Left della quarta immagine
    imgPosArray(4, 2) = 300   ' Top della quarta immagine

    imgWidth = 300 ' Larghezza delle immagini
    imgHeight = 200 ' Altezza delle immagini
    imgCounter = 0
    slideIndex = pptPresentation.Slides.Count + 1 ' Continua dopo l'ultima slide

    ' Inizia a scorrere le immagini nella cartella
    imgName = Dir(imgFolderPath & "*.jpg") ' Cambia l'estensione se necessario

    ' Aggiungi un controllo se non ci sono immagini
    If imgName = "" Then
        MsgBox "Non sono state trovate immagini nella cartella!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Inizia il ciclo per inserire le immagini
    Do While imgName <> ""
        imgCounter = imgCounter + 1
        
        ' Se imgCounter Mod 4 = 1, crea una nuova diapositiva
        If imgCounter Mod 4 = 1 Then
            Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(slideIndex, ppLayoutBlank)
            slideIndex = slideIndex + 1
        End If

        imgPath = imgFolderPath & imgName

        ' Verifica se il file immagine esiste
        If Dir(imgPath) <> "" Then
            ' Verifica il file immagine
            MsgBox "Tentativo di inserimento immagine: " & imgPath
            
            ' Calcola la posizione dell'immagine corrente
            Dim imgRow As Integer
            imgRow = ((imgCounter - 1) Mod 4) + 1

            ' Aggiungi l'immagine alla slide
            On Error GoTo GestioneErrore
            pptSlide.Shapes.AddPicture imgPath, msoFalse, msoTrue, imgPosArray(imgRow, 1), imgPosArray(imgRow, 2), imgWidth, imgHeight
            MsgBox "Immagine inserita correttamente: " & imgPath
        Else
            MsgBox "Immagine non trovata: " & imgPath
        End If

        ' Carica la prossima immagine
        imgName = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox "Le immagini sono state aggiunte alla presentazione PowerPoint esistente!"
    Exit Sub

GestioneErrore:
    MsgBox "Errore durante l'inserimento dell'immagine: " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    Exit Sub

End Sub

I would like to have a quick solution to the Error Run Time 5

Remove the line On Error GoTo GestioneErrore to see where the error is raised. Also, Single is probably not the optimal data type for image sizes.

Excel doesn't know what ppLayoutBlank is and should throw the compile error Variable not defined if you're using Option Explicit at the top of the module (hopefully you are). If you don't, I don't know which run-time error would occur. You could deal with this using a constant Const ppLayoutBlank As Long = 12. If this isn't related, then you must have a reference to the PowerPoint library created and it's sad that you are not reaping the benefits of early binding with e.g. Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application: Dim pptPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation... enabling IntelliSense.

I guess the problem is in the line If Dir(imgPath) <> "" Then. It breaks the operation of the Dir function.
Since Dir returned the particular file name, you don't need to additionally check if file exists.
    Do While imgName <> ""
        imgCounter = imgCounter + 1
        
        ' Se imgCounter Mod 4 = 1, crea una nuova diapositiva
        If imgCounter Mod 4 = 1 Then
            Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(slideIndex, ppLayoutBlank)
            slideIndex = slideIndex + 1
        End If

        imgPath = imgFolderPath & imgName

        ' Verifica se il file immagine esiste
            
        ' Calcola la posizione dell'immagine corrente
        Dim imgRow As Integer
        imgRow = ((imgCounter - 1) Mod 4) + 1

        ' Aggiungi l'immagine alla slide
        On Error GoTo GestioneErrore
        pptSlide.Shapes.AddPicture imgPath, msoFalse, msoTrue, imgPosArray(imgRow, 1), imgPosArray(imgRow, 2), imgWidth, imgHeight

        ' Carica la prossima immagine
        imgName = Dir
    Loop


Good catch, but this will only prevent that the code finds more than 1 image - it doesn't explain the runtime error

@FunThomas OP didn't provide enough information, and these items can relate each other. At least, the modified code works.

Works for me either, but it still doesn't answer OPs question "Why is my code giving as result Run time error 5?" If OP doesn't provide enough information, it's better to ask for clarification in the comments first.

@FunThomas Sure, Gustav already asked. I guess you don't think what OP is interesting for the answer to this question rather than to have the working code as it wrote at the end.

Sure, only that you don't know if your code is working for OP or not as you don't know the reason for the error. The additional Dir is destroying the Loop, but it is not causing the error. And even if the code would work for OP, it still doesn't the answer the question. After all, we are here at StackOverflow.com and not at `FreeCodingService.Com

@FunThomas OP will be able to test the code and ask for further clarifications. I don't see any `FreeCodingService' here. Anyway, I act on my own following site rules.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
